# ssh into elastic beanstalk and run program: Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have a question,I want to ssh into my elastic beanstalk and run `scrapyd`,and it has error :

```
exceptions.OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dbs'
```

Please help me or give me some directions. Thank you very much!!!

Or if there is method I can write config file directly in .ebextensions/  .It would be great

This is my terminal output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 ~]$ cd /opt/python/
[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 python]$ source run/baselinenv/bin/activate
(baselinenv)[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 python]$ scrapyd
-bash: scrapyd：命令找不到
(baselinenv)[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 python]$ source ondeck/env 
(baselinenv)[ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4 python]$ scrapyd
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 642, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 376, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 441, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 452, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 405, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application', passphrase)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 210, in loadValueFromFile
    exec fileObj in d, d
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/txapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    application = get_application()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/__init__.py", line 14, in get_application
    return appfunc(config)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/app.py", line 22, in application
    poller = QueuePoller(config)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/poller.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.update_projects()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/poller.py", line 30, in update_projects
    self.queues = get_spider_queues(self.config)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 14, in get_spider_queues
    os.makedirs(dbsdir)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
exceptions.OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dbs'

Failed to load application: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dbs'
```

Comment: run `scrapyd`  with root, is it fine?

Comment: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/